# Android Service takes too long to update

Tags: android, android-service

Hello I have implemented a service that broadcasts the current location. the thing is the first time it updates it gives me 0.0 lat and 0.0 lon, which ruins the UI.how can I fix this?
Here is the code, thank you

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
protected LocationManager locationManager;

final static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";
MyLocListener myloc = new MyLocListener();
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
@Override public void onDestroy() {

};
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

 final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

LocationListener ll = new MyLocListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 0, ll);
Location location = new Location("abc");

ll.onLocationChanged(location);
Log.d("Last", ""+location.getLatitude());

return START_STICKY;
}

private class MyLocListener implements LocationListener {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.d("1provider",location.toString());
Log.d("1Provider LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
Log.d("1Provider LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");



Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("location", location);
intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("1Provider DIsabled", "Provider Disabled");
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("1Provider Enabled", "Provider Enabled");
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("1Provider Changed", "Service Status Changed");
}
     }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this 
`Location location = new Location("abc");`
`ll.onLocationChanged(location);` in `onStartCommand()` ?

Comment: oh, it was an old method, i already deleted it.

Comment: That's why you was getting empty location. By the way `myloc` and `criteria` are unused in your `service`.

Comment: thanks, how can i use them then?

Comment: Take a look at `LocationManager.getBestProvider()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The onLocationChanged() method usually returns 0 on the first occasion - just check for this value and don't update the UI. As to it taking too long, it can take a while so run your service as an AsyncTask when getting the location, so that your UI thread is waiting around, and then update the UI when you get a return from the AsyncTask.

Comment: So in this case I would check in the background the location until it is different than 0.0 0.0?

Comment: Yes, in your onLocationChanged() method, if location.getLatitude() == 0.0 etc, then don't update.

Comment: In my LocationService, I save the locations to a database but I also check to see if it is the same as the last location saved (meaning the person hasn't moved) and I don't save it in the database (because I don't want to fill the database with lots of the same points). In my UI, I have an AsyncTask which reads the locations from the database.